# How do I send non-cloudwatch JSON events to Splunk from Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: json, parsing, terraform, splunk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to send a non-cloudwatch event to Splunk from Kinesis Firehose. I am processing the event with a Lambda and feeding it back into the Firehose in the following format ([required for Firehose](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html)):

```
{ 
    "records": [
        {
          "recordId": "2345678",
          "result": "Ok",
          "data": [base64-encoded custom JSON]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, it's throwing a vague parsing error once it gets to Splunk, with a help link that goes nowhere:

```
"errorCode":"Splunk.InvalidDataFormat","errorMessage":"The data is not formatted correctly. To see how to properly format data for Raw or Event HEC endpoints, see Splunk Event Data (http://dev.splunk.com/view/event-collector/SP-CAAAE6P#data)"
```

What am I missing here? It seems strange that the HEC endpoint wouldn't be able to parse the messages coming from Firehose in their standard format.

I am sending the message to an HEC Event endpoint, using the splunk_configuration block in an [aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream Terraform module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.html#splunk-destination).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! For posterity, since this isn't well-documented:

Your `data` field in the Kinesis Firehose payload needs to be a base64-encoded object that follows the [Splunk event collector spec](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/Data/FormateventsforHTTPEventCollector).

As long as *both* Firehose and Splunk can read the payload that the Lambda returns, it shouldn't throw an error.

Here's the code for the Kinesis Firehose transformer Lambda (node12 runtime):

```
/*
* Transformer for sending Kinesis Firehose events to Splunk
*
* Properly formats incoming messages for Splunk ingestion
* Returned object gets fed back into Kinesis Firehose and sent to Splunk
*/

'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let success = 0; // Number of valid entries found
    let failure = 0; // Number of invalid entries found
    let dropped = 0; // Number of dropped entries

    /* Process the list of records and transform them to adhere to Splunk specs */
    const output = event.records.map((record) => {
        try {
            const entry = (Buffer.from(record.data, 'base64')).toString('utf8');

            /*
             * IMPORTANT: `data` object should follow Splunk event formatting specs prior to encoding.
             * Otherwise, it will throw a parsing error.
             * https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.3/Data/FormateventsforHTTPEventCollector
             */
            const obj = {
                sourcetype: "aws:firehose:json", // Required, will error
                event: JSON.parse(entry)
            }
            const payload = (Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf8')).toString('base64');
            success++;
            return {
                recordId: record.recordId,
                result: 'Ok',
                data: payload,
            };
        } catch (e) {
            failure++
            console.error(e.message());
            return {
                recordId: record.recordId,
                result: 'ProcessingFailed'
            };
        }
    });
    console.log(`Processing completed.  Successful records ${success}. Failed records ${failure}.`);
    callback(null, {records: output});
}
```